# Why we need 1,2,4,8 bytes to store logical variable in fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I don't understand that since **logical** type only has **two** cases: `true` and `false`, then why we need `logical(1)`,`logical(2)`,`logical(4)`,`logical(8)` in Fortran?

We just need `1 bit`.

Can somebody give an explanation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, Fortran *doesn't* say that we have logical types taking up 1, 2, 4 and 8 bytes each, and they certainly aren't `logical(1)`, `logical(2)`, `logical(4)`, and `logical(8)`.  An implementation may *choose* to offer those, calling them those names.

A logical variable can indeed be of only two values.  From the (F90, although F2008 says the same in a different place) standard 4.3.2.2:

> The **logical type** has two values which represent true and false.
>
> A processor must provide one or more **representation methods** for data of type logical.  Each such method is characterized by a value for a type parameter called the **kind** type parameter.

[Emphasis here and later verbatim.]

For a logical type of default kind the rules of storage association (14.6.3.1) say that:

> (1) A nonpointer scalar object of type default integer, default real, or default logical occupies a single numeric storage unit.
> (5) A nonpointer scalar object of type [..] nondefault logical [..] occupies a single **unspecified storage unit** that is different for each case.

So, the compiler must offer a logical type which is of the same size as an integer and real type, but, equally, it can offer representations taking up 1 bit, 1 byte, or whatever.  The kind number, and size, for any given representation (hence my first paragraph: the question isn't universally valid) is implementation-specific.  That said, there is no `SELECTED_LOGICAL_KIND` (or such) intrinsic until Fortran 2023.

As to why multiple representations can be useful, that comes down to offering a choice, perhaps for special cases such as for arrays and ideal memory management (some people like to play non-portable tricks).  However, memory access/alignment requirements suggest that a scalar logical would be at least one byte (or padding make it the same).  For C interoperability (F2003+) there is a kind `C_BOOL` corresponding to the companion C processor's `_Bool`, which needn't be the same size.

Comment: `SELECTED_LOGICAL_KIND` has been added in Fortran 2023.  https://fortran.bcs.org/2022/AGM22_Reid.pdf or the specification have details.

Answer (score 4):

> LOGICAL
>
> ---
>
> The FORTRAN standard requires logical variables to be the same size   as INTEGER/REAL >variables (see the chapter on memory
>   management)   although only one bit is really needed to implement this
>   type.
>
> The values used to implement the logical constants .TRUE. and
>   .FALSE. differ:
>
> ```
>           |    VMS     |    Sun    |   IRIX    |    -----------|------------|-----------|-----------|-----------
> .TRUE.    |    -1      |     1     |     1     |    -----------|------------|-----------|-----------|-----------
> .FALSE.   |     0      |     0     |     0     |    -----------|------------|-----------|-----------|-----------
> ```
>
> Unix machines naturally adopted the C convention, VMS has a seemingly
>   strange value for .TRUE., however on a closer look you will see that
>   if .FALSE. is "all bits 0", .TRUE. should be "all bits 1", in two's 
>   complement signed integers the number with all bits set to 1 is -1.

http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch2-3.html

It looks like its for simpler memory management

http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch2-19.html

Comment: Actually, this is not entirely true.  As I understand it, the Fortran standard only defines that the first *bit* of the variable as the "meaningful" bit.  So if you are testing for nonzero to mean true, you aren't guaranteed to be standards-compliant.  If you assign "2" to a logical variable, strictly speaking, this will be interpreted as a .FALSE. since the first bit is zero.