# Is there a portable way to select the size of a LOGICAL variable?

Tags: fortran

I know there is `logical_kinds` in `iso_fortran_env`, but there seems to be no equivalent of e.g. `int32` or `int64` for logicals and, as far as I know, there is no guarantee the kind parameters for logicals and integers are the same (Cf. the `-kind=unique` flag for the NAG compiler). So, if I have something like:

```
integer(kind=int64) :: my_int
```

Is there some way to find out what is the appropriate kind (if any) for a logical variable that has the same size as `my_int`? In particular, something that would work in a `parameter` definition.

Comment: Unless `int64` is the default kind for integer, why do you expect any such logical type to exist of that size? You could enumerate over all logical kinds to test storage size, but there's no guarantee there would be a match. What do you want to happen when there is not corresponding type?

Comment: You can see more about what "portably" you can say about logical kinds in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22125504/3157076), and if you want to look at automating enumeration to look at properties, we have [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25534202/3157076) you can adapt.

Comment: @francescalus I'm dealing with legacy code that assumes logicals and integers have the same size and does some nasty low-level stuff (binary dumps, raw memory copying, etc.). The code uses `real*8` and is compiled with `-i8`, and I want to convert it to using proper kinds.

Comment: "I'm dealing with legacy code that assumes logicals and integers have the same size" For default kind integer and logical this is fine and is guaranteed, but I'm afraid the moment you throw -i8 at it all bets are off. You will have to look at your compiler documentation in that case

Comment: @IanBush I know. The code assumes it will work, and apparently it has worked so far with the main compilers at least. But that's why I want to update and not rely on `-i8` or other out-of-spec extensions.

Comment: It is not just assumption, it MUST work. The standard does require that default integer and default logical have the same storage size.

Comment: @VladimirF but not with `-i8`, which is how this code is supposed (expected) to be compiled.

Comment: The problem is the moment you start using the -i8 flag nothing is portable any more - it is totally up to the compiler precisely what -i8 means and all guarantees given by the standard go out the window. I personally think that flags that change the kinds of variable types are just plain evil and wish compilers didn't support them - coding it correctly will save you much grief and pain in the long run

Comment: @Jellby If you specifically only change the default real kind and not other types, you are in your own. You are breaking what the standard promises. If that breaks something, it is your fault.

Comment: Well, that's what I want to fix. I know it works with `-i8` and I want to make it work similarly with `kind=...`, because I can't rely on `-i8`.

Comment: OK, now I get what you are after. In that case you can just use `LOGICAL(kind=your_integer_kind)` and make some assert that will stop everything if the storage size does not match. It should.